# How to use two properties to display in Vaadin ListSelect?

Tags: java, vaadin

I use a Vaadin ListSelect to show the options.I have a title of my template as display name but I want to add one more property (id) from templateContainer to display. How can I do it?

```
ListSelect select = new ListSelect("Templates", templatesContainer);
select.setItemCaptionPropertyId("title");
```

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
ListSelect select = new ListSelect("Templates", templatesContainer) {
    @Override
    public String getItemCaption(Object itemId) {
        MyTemplate t = (MyTemplate) itemId;
        return t.getTitle() + "-" + t.getId();
    }
};
```

Or if you use container you can use it directly:

```
ListSelect select = new ListSelect("Templates", templatesContainer) {
    @Override
    public String getItemCaption(Object itemId) {
        Container c = getContainerDataSource();
        String title = (String) c.getContainerProperty(itemId, "title").getValue();
        Integer id = (Integer) c.getContainerProperty(itemId, "id").getValue();
        return title + "-" + id;
    }
};
```